# getting gmail Contacts

Tags: javascript, google-plus, google-oauth

I am trying to get g mail contacts ,with oauth google plus  api javascript i am to get his profile,        but unfortunately i am not able to get all email of contacts,but i mention every thing correct in scope and all,
 can any one suggest me how can i get gmail contacts.

I am using below js :
https://apis.google.com/js/client.js
 i wrote bellow code to get contact emails

```
          var authParams = gapi.auth.getToken(); // from Google oAuth

          authParams.alt = 'json';

          $.ajax({
            url: 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            data: authParams,
            success: function(text) { 
                alert("text?????????"+JSON.stringify(text.feed));

                }
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

> The Contacts API has a hard limit to the number of results it can return at a time even if you explicitly request all possible results. If the requested feed has more fields than can be returned in a single response, the API truncates the feed and adds a "Next" link that allows you to request the rest of the response.

[Source](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/reference#ContactsFeed)

So you have to take the response, get the `Next` link from it, and make another request to get additional contacts.